# How to redirect following URL in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am beginner to `php`, here is my URL,

```
http://example.eg.com/demo-event one/feed/ (with space event one)
```

to

```
http://example.eg.com/demo-eventone/feed/ (with out space)
```

thank you.

Comment: why dont you improve your database data? I assume the the url keyword "event one" is coming from db. So, you can have "event one" as title to your page, and add "event-one" OR "eventone" OR "event_one" for url (or anything like that), without using any htaccess rules. If no other changes occur to your links, i would prefer this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(.*)$" /$1$2 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: this is my old URL `http://example.eg.cc/events/category/private-new york/feed/` and I want to redirect to `http://example.eg.cc/events/category/private-newyork/feed/`

Comment: Yes this rule takes care of that. Makes sure this is placed in root .htaccess (one directory above `/events/`) and is the very first rule.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

This was worked for me
By placing url in double quotes `""`

```
Redirect "http://example.eg.cc/events/category/private-new york/feed/" "http://example.eg.cc/events/category/private-newyork/feed/"
```